# How to login successfully with details from local Storage [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, local-storage

So basically i store the details entered by the user in the register form into local HTML storage... And i have checked that the details ARE stored in local storage, however, when i try to log in with such information (username and password) in the login form.... it doesn't work. So how would i be able to log in the login form successfully?? In other words, how would i be able to get the data for username and password entered in the register form (which is stored in local storage) and use that to compare with user's input in login form to validate the login process?? Here are files:

Comment: what exactly is the question here?

Comment: Okay apologies... what i am trying to do is login basically, but when i try to login, i get my alert message saying invalid user or pass, even though i use the data that are already stored in local storage. e.g: stored user is aaa and pass is aaa, if i typed those in login form, it would say incorrect username or password. SO how would i be able to log in? I am confused

Comment: well what are the values for 'storedUserName', 'storedPassWord', 'username' and 'password' inside of validlogin() ?

Comment: You store array of users as `allEntries`, but you are getting the user info as `UserName`, `PassWord`, etc

Comment: Doing login validation on the client is wrong. The user can easily get around it. Real login verification needs to be done on the server.

Comment: I'm just doing this website privately for myself just to learn, otherwise yes, i'd take your point of course

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to compare them to user and pass, not username and password:

```
var entry = localStorage.getItem("entry");
console.log("username: " + entry.user + "password: " + entry.pas);
if(username.value == entry.user && password.value == entry.pass) {
    alert('You have successfully logged in.');

}
```

In the browser pres CTRL + SHIFT + I, and if it's not open select "Console"

Comment: It still says invalid username or password

Comment: are you entering in the form the same data you are reading from the entry? Like in your example "vvv" and "vvv"?

Comment: yeah and i have tried aaa and aaa but still the same issue

Comment: how about you try console.log(entry.user); before the if, and see what it prints out.

Comment: i get nothing, i opened the console log but nothing is printed or achieved from that code

Comment: username: undefined password: undefined (output in console log).... so basically my user and pass are not collected or?...

Answer (score 1):

These lines won't work:

```
var storedUserName = localStorage.getItem('UserName');
var storedPassWord = localStorage.getItem('PassWord');
var storedEmailAddress = localStorage.getItem('EmailAddress');
```

`savedata()` doesn't save each field to its own item, it just saves the `entry` object as a whole. So you need to retrieve that and parse it.

```
var entryJSON = localStorage.getItem('entry');
if (!entryJSON) {
    alert("Nothing stored!");
    return;
}
var entry = JSON.parse(entryJSON);
var storedUserName = entry.user;
var storedPassWord = entry.pass;
var storedEmailAddress = entry.email;
```

To search `allEntries`, you need to use a loop:

```
function validlogin(event) {
    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;

    var entriesJSON = localStorage.getItem('allEntries');
    if (!entriesJSON) {
        alert("Nothing stored!");
        event.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
    var allEntries = JSON.parse(entriesJSON);
    for (var i = 0; i < allEntries.length; i++) {
        var entry = allEntries[i];
        var storedUserName = entry.user;
        var storedPassWord = entry.pass;
        var storedEmailAddress = entry.email;
        if (username == storedUserName && password == storedPassWord) {
            alert("Successfully logged in!");
            return;
    }
    alert('Invalid Username or Password! Please try again.');
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location="Login.html";
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the whole application, I can't really figure out what's going wrong. Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: added the fiddle, take a look at it :)

Comment: I needed to add `event.preventDefault()` when it alerts "Nothing stored". Then it works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/s1fswLo5/3/. The fiddle doesn't have any code for creating users, so all logins fail.

Comment: I've made another fiddle that creates one user first. Username = `barry` Password = `barrypassword`. If you enter this correct username it doesn't redirect.

Comment: i typed in the only user detail in local storage and it still wont let me log in.. programming is annoying :(

Comment: when i made an account with user  "aaa" and pass "aaa", it logs on normal, however when i made a second account  with user "bbb" and pass "bbb", and i try log on with those correct details.... it first shows invalid alert box, and then the successful alert box and then doesn't redirect me with the PHP file

Comment: So you haven't got a clue??

Comment: In your fiddle, you have the "Incorrect login" alert in the `else` clause. That means you'll get that message for every user that doesn't match until it finds a match. It should be after the loop is done, as in my answer. https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/s1fswLo5/8/